# Angular - How to minimise same code usage?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm not sure how to handle and change below implementation better.

I've two subscription method which re-assigns the value like below.

```
public patientLastStatus = "";

this.treatmentStageOne.subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp) {
        this.patientLastStatus = "Passed";
      }
    });
this.treatmentStageTwo.subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp) {
        this.patientLastStatus = "Still in Observation";
      }
    });
```

I understand , above are completely two different subscription. 
Here, the value of `this.patientLastStatus` is only re-assigned. but i don't understand on what basis Sonarqube shows me like **Update or refactor this function so that its implementation doesn't duplicate the one on line 88.**

How can changes that in better way?

Helps much appreciated

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract this logic into a higher order function that takes in what the new assignment value would be:

```
const conditionalChange = newValue => 
  resp => {
    if (resp) {
      this.patientLastStatus = newValue;
    }
  }
```

Now you can just re-use it in both subscriptions without duplicating the code:

```
this.treatmentStageOne.subscribe(conditionalChange("Passed"));
this.treatmentStageTwo.subscribe(conditionalChange("Still in Observation"));
```

Comment: This looks much better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Sonarqube is throwing a warning because it sees a duplication.Try `this.patientLastStatus` updating through a method.

```
public patientLastStatus = "";

public updatePateintStatus = (status)=>{
   this.patientLastStatus = status;
}
this.treatmentStageOne.subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp) {
        this.updatePateintStatus("Passed");
      }
    });
this.treatmentStageTwo.subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp) {
        this.updatePateintStatus("Still in observations...");
      }
    });
```